Download PNG and MP3 files from Azure Blob Storage in python
please I would like to know if there are any best practices for downloading files (images, audios or others) from azure blob storage?
At the moment I give my connection string every time to read/write to the blob Storage, can I not Hardcode this? And also when I download the blobs it's either locally or in memory to use them in my code, what's good to do?
I've read about Blob Storage Bindings but I have the impression that they are only used with Azure Functions, whereas I want to use them in normal Python code, i.e. without triggers or anything, just a code to download images and audios and concatenate them.
Also I can't read image and audio files well, I get errors all the time.
Here is my python code :
def merge_image_audio():
    """
    Merge PNG with mp3 files.
    """

    # get Azure Container Client 
    azure_connection_string = os.getenv("AZURE_CONNECTION_STRING")
    container_client = get_container_client(azure_connection_string, AZURE_CONTAINER_NAME)

    # List blobs in the "temp" folder
    blob_list = container_client.list_blobs(name_starts_with="temp/")
    # Initialize lists to store blob data
    image_blob_data_list = []
    audio_blob_data_list = []

    # Download PNG and MP3 files and store blob data in the lists
    for blob in blob_list:
        if blob.name.endswith('.png'):
            # Create a blob client
            blob_client = BlobClient.from_connection_string(conn_str= azure_connection_string, container_name=AZURE_CONTAINER_NAME, blob_name=blob.name)
            
            # Download the blob data directly into memory
            blob_data = blob_client.download_blob()

            # Create a temporary file to store the downloaded data
            with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(suffix=".png", delete=False) as image_temp_file:
                image_temp_file.write(blob_data.readall())
                image_temp_file_path = image_temp_file.name

            # Append blob data to the list
            image_blob_data_list.append(image_temp_file_path)
            image_temp_file.close()

        elif blob.name.endswith(".mp3"):
            # Create a blob client
            blob_client = BlobClient.from_connection_string(conn_str= azure_connection_string, container_name= AZURE_CONTAINER_NAME, blob_name=blob.name)
            
            # Download the blob data directly into memory
            blob_data = blob_client.download_blob()

            # Create a temporary file to store the downloaded data
            with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(suffix=".mp3", delete=False) as audio_temp_file:
                audio_temp_file.write(blob_data.readall())
                audio_temp_file_path = audio_temp_file.name
            
            # Append blob data to the list
            audio_blob_data_list.append(audio_temp_file_path)
            audio_temp_file.close()

I mostly have problems with images, I've tried to read them with BytesIO() and Image.open(), but I get errors like this all the time:

Exception: AttributeError: 'PngImageFile' object has no attribute 'shape'
Exception: UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x89 in position 0: invalid start byte moviepy

PS: I am using Azure Functions V2

Try using azcopy with subprocess


I want to use them in normal Python code, i.e. without triggers or anything, just a code to download images and audios

To download PNG and MP3 files use below Python code with which I have got desired results and has no triggers as you wanted:
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient

rith_cs = "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=rith89;AccountKey=qB6ipdzpohWGufPQ==;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net"
rith_bsc = BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string(rith_cs)
rith_con_name = "rithwik"
rith_png_name = "testimg.png"
rith_mp3_name = "mp3test.mp3"
rith_local_png_path = r"C:\Users\Downloads\downloaded_file.png"
rith_local_mp3_path = r"C:\Users\Downloads\downloaded_file.mp3"
rith_pngcl = rith_bsc.get_blob_client(container=rith_con_name, blob=rith_png_name)
with open(rith_local_png_path, "wb") as f:
    f.write(rith_pngcl.download_blob().readall())
print(f"Hello Rithwik, PNG file downloaded at {rith_local_png_path}")
rith_mp3cl = rith_bsc.get_blob_client(container=rith_con_name, blob=rith_mp3_name)
with open(rith_local_mp3_path, "wb") as f:
    f.write(rith_mp3cl.download_blob().readall())
print(f"Hello Rithwik, MP3 file downloaded at {rith_local_mp3_path}")

rith_con_name is container name.
In Storage Account:

Output:



Thank you for your reply, is there a way not to download the files locally, I only need to retrieve them to concatenate them into a video, and my project needs to be in production (deployed on azure), I think it's not really adequate in my case to upload them locally

AFAIK, files will be downloaded and I'll try to check if there is any way to do without downloading.
